# Kicad assigning net names randomly

Tags: pcb-design, schematics, kicad

I'm running into an inconsistent behavior related to net naming in Kicad, where the same net connection (literally the same sheet duplicated multiple times in a hierarchical layout) ends up with different names. As you can see in the image, each LED driver in the schematic has an output label named MCU_PWM, and the MCU has a corresponding label named RLED_PWM, GLED_PWM and BLED_PWM. However, on the board, two of the nets end up getting named MCU_PWM and the third is named RLED_PWM. Any idea why this is happening?

[image: Top hierarchical schematic. Of note are the PWM outputs on the LED drivers.]

[image: PWM inputs on the board.]

Comment: Try adding net names in the toplevel sheet. I don't know how it would choose a name only from hierarchical labels - why would the ones in your MCU override the ones in the drivers?

Comment: That did it, thank you!